# Best practice to report different types of failures from function in C#

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

Very General Newbie question: what is the best way to report different failure conditions from a function.  Consider the following scenario:

```
public class ResourceHandler
{
    public void Method1(SomeDataType somedata)
    {
        CreateResource(somedata);
        if(ResourceExistsButContainsFailures())
            //report that resource was created successfuly but it is unusable
        if(ResourceExistsButItsEmpty())
            //report that resource was created successfuly but it is empty
        if(ResourseDoesNotExist())
            //report that resource failed to be created successfuly
    }
}
```

The idea is that in case of failure, the consumer of the `ResourceHandler` would then make a decision on how to proceed based on the type of failure that occurred when executing `Method1()`.

Question: throwing different custom types of exception for each of the failure conditions seems like most obvious approach.  Consider `ResourceFailedException`, `ResourceEmptyException`, and `ResourceNullException` respectively is thrown for each failure condition.
Is it the right approach, or is there some other pattern that I should be following?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: I like the exception approach, but just so long as the exception is just that, an exception.  You don't want exceptions to be used to to define normal flow through the program.

Comment: As suggested, throwing exceptions is the right option if the situations are indeed exceptional. In most cases, you should only be throwing an exception if you have already caught an exception thrown by other code or you did some prevalidation that found a situation that would cause an exception to be thrown if you proceeded. For situations that aren't exceptional, the alternative would be to define an `enum` and return the appropriate value from that to indicate the state.

Comment: Indeed, all of your situations seem to be ones you're foreseeing and reporting on normally (status enum), and thus don't seem to truly qualify as "exceptional". Questions that ask "what is the best.." are usually intrinsically off topic for SO.